# why is executing GetRequestStream making the method returns?

Tags: c#, ftp

I am trying to upload a file to an ftp server, which using Ftp zilla seems to be working, and i can log in from opera. Here's the code i wrote to do it, basically ripped off from the internet. While exceuting this method, when reaching GetRequestStream and well waiting for a bit for the server to do its work, i can clearly see in the visual studio debugger that the method never reaches the line after GetRequestStream.

```
        FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(_url);
        ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);

        ftp.KeepAlive = true;
        ftp.UseBinary = true;
        ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(_filefullname);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        fs.Close();

        Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
        ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        ftpstream.Close();
```

Comment: So what makes you think its making your method return? Is it throwing a timeout exception of some sort? Are you setting the file name in the URL?

Comment: Sounds like it's throwing an exception...

Comment: Well in the visual studio debugger i see that it skips stuff then jumps directly to the end of the method.

Edit:
URL is there correctly.

Comment: It indeed was an exception that i did not notice. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indeed was an exception that i did not notice as Ron and Buddy mentioned